# In what way does Firenze propose Hagrid to abandon his attempt?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* chapter 27, the centaur Firenze asks Harry to pass on a warning to Hagrid, saying

> His attempt is not working. He would do better to abandon it.

Harry delivers the message later in the same chapter.  We learn only in chapter 30 what the warning was referring to: Hagrid had brought the giant Grawp and is hiding him in the Forbidden Forest.  “His attempt” probably refers to Hagrid wanting to teach and civilize Grawp.

My question is what did Firenze mean by “abandon it”?  Now that Grawp is in the forest, what else could Hagrid do than continue teaching him?  It would be a very bad idea to send Grawp away to Muggle lands or back to the other giants.  Even if the attempt wasn't working, what did Firenze suppose Hagrid would have to do?

Comment: Centaurs regarded the forest as "theirs" (I'll need to hunt up the quotes). As such, it didn't matter to them WHAT Hagrid would do with Grawp, as long as Grawp's presence was removed.

Comment: @DVK Probably wanted Grawp killed but that isn't stated anywhere, they do attack him at least once.

Comment: Given Firenze was Hagrid's friend, and Hagrid's attempt at "civilizing" Grawp was leading to serious injuries to him, I'd always assumed he'd asked this as one guy telling his friend to stop pursuing a course of useless action that's been hurting him. So whether or not Grawp is *removed* from the forest wouldn't enter into it. After all, the Forest has a bunch of things worse than a single runty Giant! Once Hagrid was out of the equation, the Law of the Jungle could do what it will, as it does for all other Forest inhabitants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought he meant Hagrid should stop trying to mediate between the Centaurs and get him to be accepted and forgiven by them.

[From here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Firenze) we can see that Hagrid and Firenze knew each other as they met at least once before the 5th book(in the Forbidden Forest in the 1st book).

> Firenze saved Harry Potter in the forest from Lord Voldemort,
>   frightening him away and carrying Harry on his back to safety. Despite
>   his heroics, his herd saw this as a dishonourable act, as they
>   considered themselves too great to be ridden by humans.
>
> About four years later, in March 1996, Albus Dumbledore, Headmaster of
>   Hogwarts, hired him to teach Divination in Sybill Trelawney's stead,
>   after she was sacked by Dolores Umbridge. But once again, the other
>   centaurs saw this as servitude, and his colony attacked and banished
>   him. **They would have killed him were it not for the intervention of
>   Rubeus Hagrid**.
>
> Bane: "Firenze! What are you doing? You have a human on your back!
>   Have you no shame? Are you a common mule?" Firenze: "Do you realise
>   who this is? This is the Potter boy. The quicker he leaves this
>   forest, the better." Bane: "What have you been telling him? Remember,
>   Firenze, we are sworn not to set ourselves against the heavens. Have
>   we not read what is to come in the movements of the planets? […]
>   Centaurs are concerned with what has been foretold! It is not our
>   business to run around like donkeys after stray humans in our forest!"
>   Firenze: "Do you not see that unicorn? Do you not understand why it
>   was killed? Or have the planets not let you in on that secret? I set
>   myself against what is lurking in this forest, Bane, yes, with humans
>   alongside me if I must." — Bane scolds Firenze for letting Harry ride
>   him
>
> **He was friendly with Hagrid**, and seemed to get on quite well with
>   Harry, who was on speaking terms with him unlike most students, who
>   found him intimidating.

[From here:](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rubeus_Hagrid#Years_at_Hogwarts)

> when the Centaur's herd turned on him for entering into "the servitude
>   of a human" by accepting the position at Hogwarts as a favour to
>   Headmaster Dumbledore, it was Hagrid who saved him.

**Not canon, but my logic**

I don't think unless the book absolutely says so, that Firenze would want Grawp abandoned like he was abandoned by his kind. Remember he has compassion, he came to the aid of Harry and he stood up for what he believed in (even though he had attempts on his life). Firenze it doesn't appear would have told Hagrid to kill his brother or back done, as he himself wasn't backing down.

Answer (score 0):

He probably wanted Grawp killed, or sent away, and because he was disrupting the normally semi-peaceful forest life.

Comment: I thought he meant Hagrid should stop trying to mediate between the Centaurs.